# ScrollView Breaking When Adding Adjacent Component in React/js

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am working with React Native Web and Reactjs and I have the following code on one of my pages.

What I'm trying to do is make the background image and footer scrollable, while keeping the header (HorizontalNavBar) fixed at the top,. The ScrollView works fine when I don't try to render the VerticalNavBar over it, but breaks when I try to do so. It doesn't even work if the VerticalNavBar is present but rendering null.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Attaching a screenshot. Thx!

```
  var Home = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
          return {
              source: homeImageSmall,
              windowWidth: window.innerWidth,
              tutorialDirection: 'row',
              verticalNavOpen: false};
      },

      closeVerticalNav: function() {
         this.setState({verticalNavOpen: false})
      },
      openVerticalNav: function() {
          this.setState({verticalNavOpen: true})
      },
      render() {
          return (
              <View>
                <View style={{flex:0}}>
                    <HorizontalNavBar verticalNavOpen = {this.state.verticalNavOpen} openVerticalNav = {this.openVerticalNav}/>
                    <ScrollView style={{flex:0}}>
                        <View>
                            <Image
                                style={contentStyle.backGroundImage}
                                source={this.state.source}>
                                    <View style = {[styles.doubleIphoneWrapper, {flexDirection: this.state.tutorialDirection}]}>
                                        <Tutorial content={Baseball} name={"Baseball"}/>
                                        <Tutorial content={Football} name={"Football"}/>
                                    </View>
                            </Image>
                            <Footer/>
                        </View>
                    </ScrollView>
                    <VerticalNav verticalNavOpen = {this.state.verticalNavOpen} closeVerticalNav = {this.closeVerticalNav}/>
                </View>
              </View>
    )
    }
    })
```

[image]

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that I have the VerticalNavBar position set to 'absolute.' Not sure if that's an issue or not.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had overflow: hidden in my HTML file. The above code works if I remove that and set the position of both the horizontal and vertical menus to 'fixed'. #facepalm